# Problems with wordpress nonces in Ajax call

Tags: ajax, jquery

i am having big troubles with Wordpress nonces in ajax call. Basically i am trying to trigger a custom standalone php script i made on my custom theme that send emails to admins people whenever someone press a button of sumbit notifies, the admins that the answers has been sent and admins are ready for checking. Unfortunately i am new to Wordpress i am starting to approach it, i followed the official develping on codex and i tried to implement nonces mesure otherwise obviously it gives me always the 403 forbidden http error status code. I implemendted nonces but still 403 error. I don't know what is wrong. Below i leave the code portions of the 3 main files involved. Thank you in advance.

This is my custom-jq.js file:

```
    (function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
    
        $('answer-submit-question-long-class')
        .attr('id','answerBtn');
    
        $('#answerBtn').on('click touch tap', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
        
            let answer_success_msg = "Answers have been sent";
            
            //alert(answer_success_msg );
                        
            $.ajax({
                url: ajax_answers_var.url,
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    action: 'check_nonce_ajax_answers',
                    nonce: ajax_answers_var.nonce,
                },
                success: function(data){
                    if(data){
                        console.log(data);
                        alert(answer_success_msg);
                    } 
                },
                error: function(err){
                    console.log(err);
                    alert("Sorry an error has been occurred" + err.status);
                },
                timeout: 60000
            });
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

This is the portion in functions.php file:

```
function load_custom_jquery_edit(){

wp_enqueue_script('customize-jq', 
                    get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/customize-jq.js',
                    array('jquery'),
                    "1.0.61",
                    true);

wp_localize_script('customize-jq', 'ajax_answers_var', array(
    'url' => '/wp-content/themes/mycustomtheme/notifyanswers.php',
    'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('ajax-answers-nonce')
));
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_jquery_edit');

function check_nonce_ajax_answers(){    
    if(!wp_verify_nonce(esc_html($_POST['nonce']), 'ajax-answers-nonce')){
        wp_die('Forbidden.');
    }
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_check_nonce_ajax_answers', 'check_nonce_ajax_answers');    
add_action('wp_ajax_check_nonce_ajax_answers', 'check_nonce_ajax_answers');
```

This is my standalone php script notifyanswers.php:

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.com');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");

require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-config.php');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-includes/wp-db.php');
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');


if(!is_user_logged_in()){
    wp_redirect('https://example.com/login');
    exit;
}

$user = wp_get_current_user();

$user_role = (array) $user->roles;

if($user_role[0] == "subscriber"){
    
    $headers = array("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    $to = ["emailslist@mail.com"];
    $subject = "My Subject";
    $message = "My custom message";
    
    wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    wp_die();
}
```

Sorry for my dumb question but as i said i am new to Wordpress developing and i don't really have clear yet how it works Wordpress nonce.

Comment: why are you using an escaping function when processing the nonce? This is highly unusual and not good, escaping happens on output, _not input._ It's also very bad practice to use standalone PHP files in your plugins and theme

Comment: I was really doubting that maybe it could make some troubles, i removed as you suggested because it is resonable, that isn't an input field. I removed the `esc_html()` but still throwes the 403 error.

Comment: I guarantee it is incorrect to use `esc_html` in that situation, but also you're only looking at the HTTP code, what did the response say? Also is there a reason you chose the legacy admin ajax API instead of the modern REST API? Take a look at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/,  you should also eliminate that file and use a hook that looks at the submitted values to process the result, or a REST API endpoint. Standalone PHP files in your themes for form/AJAX handling are a major security anti-pattern that cause lots of trouble for you as a dev

Comment: Absolutely, i realized it is a bad practice as you said the standalone scripts, i was very hesitant and now i am discovering that coud cause even much troubles. Thank you for your answer i will read carefully everything

Comment: change `'url' => '/wp-content/themes/mycustomtheme/notifyanswers.php',` to `site_url() . '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'`; and add the contents of `notifyanswers.php` beneath the if-condition in `check_nonce_ajax_answers`, then add a die(); afterwards and your code should work, I think. That should set you up with an ajax-endpoint rather than a standalone file & you'll be able to remove the headers & calls to wp-config.php and the like as well.